# Autorun and permanent admin rights to the .exe file using .NET

Tags: .net, windows-10

I have an app that I want to be launched automatically when system starts(app requests admin rights). But I don't want to see this dialog of providing permission for the file to act as the admin.
I use this code to add my app to the autorun

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        key.SetValue("MyApp", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
```

But when system starts, only the folder is opened.
How can I(via C# code)
1.Give permanent adm rights to the app;
2.Set the app to the autorun on the background;

Comment: You have not done enough research on it. Here is one of many  articles <http://www.howtogeek.com/218992/how-do-you-automatically-run-a-program-with-administrator-privileges-upon-user-login-in-windows/> And you need to understand that app can't give itself permissions.

Comment: @T.S. apps cant provide permissions to themselves, but there should be the way for an app, given the admin rights, give rights of the same level to another items, or just save these privileges for itself forever..

Comment: start the application via task scheduler: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472